# Duplicate query strings in url

Tags: sql, url, coldfusion, query-string

I have a site that was recently moved to a new server. It seems as though if a link on the site, or entered directly in the address bar, include a query string such as :

```
https://www.web.site?id=5314&type=course
```

It would automatically duplicate it to be:

```
https://www.web.site?id=5314&type=course&id=5314&type=course
```

Notice the duplicate url parameters?

- id=5314&type=course&**id=5314&type=course**

I've combed through my code and I cannot determine what's causing this. Is there anywhere else I should be looking?

This is a ColdFusion site running on a Windows server.

Comment: Any URL Rewrite rules involved?

Comment: What happens when you add dummy parameter to the end of the query string... does it duplicate that dummy one as well?

Comment: There's no rewrite rules that I can find and in IIS there are only the http:// to https:// rule we have set. I have tried adding a dummy parameter at the end and it duplicated that as well.

Comment: If it happens with manually entered url's it does sound like there's some rewriting going on ... somewhere.  Also, anything creative occurring in the Application.cfc ?

Comment: it could also be a `<cflocation>` call that is doing it

Comment: Does it occur with all url's or just some?

Comment: It happens with all URLs, even some pasted on a test page within the same domain. What I did to get around it for now is I used a relative urls for these query urls and it doesn't seem to duplicate them this way.

Comment: So why does it matter?  Is it breaking the code that processes the url variables?

Comment: As CF converts multiple occurrences of the same parameter name into csv lists (or arrays) that would likely break code expecting a single value.

Comment: I'll ask again, does this server have any IIS rewrite rules enabled? I ran into an issue when redirecting HTTP to HTTPS, the query string was duplicated until I made a tweak to the rewrite rule.

Comment: Can you confirm, was your link driving to "www.web.site" or "web.site"?  We just ran into an issue where our links to "web.site" without the www were causing querystring duplication and it was an IIS Rewrite issue.